# Does Rust protect me from iterator invalidation when pushing to a vector while iterating over it?

Tags: vector, iterator, rust, invalidation

Does Rust protect me from iterator invalidation here or am I just lucky with `realloc`? What guarantees are given for an iterator returned for `&'a Vec<T>`?

```
fn main() {
    let mut v = vec![0; 2];

    println!("capacity: {}", v.capacity());

    {
        let v_ref = &mut v;
        for _each in v_ref.clone() {
            for _ in 0..101 {
                (*v_ref).push(1); // ?
            }
        }
    }

    println!("capacity: {}", v.capacity());
}
```

Comment: I am not a rust expert but it looks you iterate over a clone, not the original vec.

Comment: TL;DR the answer: yes, but that only comes into play if you are actually pushing to the vector you are iterating over.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Rust, most methods take an `&self` - a *reference* to self. In most circumstances, a call like `some_string.len()` internally "expands" to something like this:

```
let a: String = "abc".to_string();
let a_len: usize = String::len(&a); // This is identical to calling `a.len()`.
```

However, consider a reference to an object: `a_ref`, which is an `&String` that references `a`. Rust is smart enough to determine whether a reference needs to be added or removed, like we saw above (`a` becomes `&a`); In this case, `a_ref.len()` expands to:

```
let a: String = "abc".to_string();
let a_ref: &String = &a;
let a_len: usize = String::len(a_ref); // This is identical to calling `a_ref.len();`. Since `a_ref` is a reference already, it doesn't need to be altered.
```

Notice that this is basically equivalent to the original example, except that we're using an explicitly-set reference to `a` rather than `a` directly.

This means that `v.clone()` expands to `Vec::clone(&v)`, and similarly, `v_ref.clone()` expands to `Vec::clone(v_ref)`, and since `v_ref`is `&v` (or, specifically, `&mut v`), we can simplify this back into `Vec::clone(&v)`. In other words, these calls are **equivalent** - calling `clone()` on a basic reference (`&`) to an object does not clone the *reference*, it clones the *referenced object*.

In other words, Tamas Hedgeus' comment is correct: *You are iterating over a new vector, which contains elements that are clones of the elements in `v`*. The item being iterated over in your `for` loop is not a `&Vec`, it's a `Vec` that is separate from `v`, and therefore iterator invalidation is not an issue.

As for your question about the guarantees Rust provides, you'll find that Rust's borrow checker handles this rather well without any strings attached.

If you were to [remove `clone()` from the `for` loop,](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=0029ac7195bf54127fc228a12dd4ba64&version=stable) though, you would receive an error message, `use of moved value: '*v_ref'`, because `v_ref` is considered 'moved' into the `for` loop when you iterate over it, and cannot be used for the remainder of the function; to avoid this, the `iter` function creates an iterator object that only *borrows* the vector, allowing you to reuse the vector after the loop ends (and the iterator is dropped). And if you were to try [iterating over and mutating `v`](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=354a24abe554b17d7e67d8e3991ef67b&version=stable) without the `v_ref` abstraction, the error reads `cannot borrow 'v' as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable`. `v` is borrowed immutably within the iterator spawned by `v.iter()` (which has type signature of `fn iter(&self) -> Iter<T>` - note, it makes a *borrow* to the vector), and will not allow you to mutate the vector as a result of Rust's borrow checker, until the iterator is dropped (at the end of the `for` loop). However, since you can have multiple *immutable* references to a single object, you can still *read* from the vector within the for loop, just not write into it.

If you need to mutate an *element* of a vector while iterating over the vector, you can use [`iter_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.iter_mut), which returns *mutable* references to one element at a time and lets you change that element *only*. You still cannot mutate the iterated vector itself with `iter_mut`, because Rust ensures that there is only *one* mutable reference to an object at a time, as well as ensuring there are no mutable references to an object in the same scope as immutable references to that object.

Comment: As an aside: The "expansion" mechanics of Rust are actually required for handling trait collisions. if `trait Foo` and `trait Bar` both implement an `fn qux(&self)`, and you have an object of type `FooBar` which implements *both* `Foo` and `Bar`, you pick the implementation to use by writing `<FooBar as Foo>::qux(&foobar_obj)` (or `as Bar` as necessary). [Per the book.](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch19-03-advanced-traits.html#fully-qualified-syntax-for-disambiguation)

Comment: *calling `clone()` on a basic reference (`&`) to an object does not clone the reference,* — not universally true.  It does clone the reference when  the referenced type does not implement `Clone`.

Comment: @Shepmaster - I wasn't aware of this. I figured that trying to call `clone` on a reference to something that doesn't define `clone` would raise an error, or that there would be a special way to clone references as compared to cloning the referenced objects to avoid confusion. TIL.